# How to unregister BroadcastReceiver associated with repeating alarm?

Tags: android, android-alarms, android-broadcast

It's unclear to me how to accomplish this, and I'm getting lost in the Android docs. I would assume this a common enough scenario though, so could someone show me the appropriate way to get hold of a BroadcastReceiver so I can unregister it (or point me in the right direction so I can educate myself) ?

**SETTING THE ALARM:**

```
registerReceiver(alarmHandler, new IntentFilter("com.blah.alarm"));
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent("com.blah.alarm"), 0);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) (this.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE ));
am.setRepeating(
        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, someCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

**UNSETTING THE ALARM:**

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this, 0, new Intent("com.blah.alarm", PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
if (pi != null) {
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE ));
    am.cancel(pi);
}
unregisterReceiver(????????); // how do I get alarmHandler ref ??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to save the `alarmHandler` reference in a variable somewhere so that you can get it when you need to call unregister()`. Android doesn't provide any method you can call to get a reference to it.

Comment: This isn't possible for me, because I wanted the option to completely destroy the app and then, possibly days, weeks? later, start the app and cancel a long running alarm. As it turns out, it seemed that using a Service instead of a BroadcastReceiver is more appropriate for this kind of task, so that's what I did and there's no longer any issue. Is that correct? So, BR if it can hold onto a ref, otherwise Service being more appropriate?

Comment: I think you are missing something. You can certainly cancel the alarm after the app has been destroyed (the alarm is stored in the Android AlarmManager). However, you cannot unregister the BroadcastReceiver after the app has been destroyed. When you register a BroadcastReceiver you are registering an in-memory object. As soon as that object goes away (garbage collected or app shutdown or app's process killed or phone rebooted), it is gone (ie: automatically unregistered). Also, if the phone reboots, all your scheduled alarms will be deleted.

Comment: I see. Well, I think that answers my original question then, cheers.